# Different socket, different setting?

Tags: laptop, battery

My thinkpad X1 is set to stop charging at 50%, which I am not sure works. When I plug in my laptop in my office, it is always charged to 100%. However, now, I am at home and my laptop says "98% available, plugged in, not charging". I didn't change any setting when I came home from my office. Why does my laptop response differently to different socket?

Comment: Where did you set it to stop charging? Have you tested other sockets? Is this repeatable behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo have an application called Energy Management which I think you are referring to. Lenovo introduced this application because having the battery charged at 100% "may decrease the battery life" According to Lenovo staff in the Lenovo forums.

The laptop will not respond differently among different sockets as all sockets produce the same amount of power (within reason) and are not able to communicate to the computer that it is a different socket. You will find that by removing the Energy Management application will make the laptop charge to 100% as any other without energy management applications would.